# Perl subroutines with named paramters

Tags: perl

While I'm trying to figure out a simple way to make a variable passed as a parameter to a subroutine immutable in the called subroutine, I came upon a [webpage](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-mutable-and-immutable-parameters/) showing the following:

> ```perl
> #!/usr/bin/perl 
>
> # Function Definition 
> sub Func(Int $variable) 
> { 
>   # Operation to be performed 
>   $variable /= 2; 
> } 
>
> # Defining a local variable 
> my $value = 20; 
>
> # Function Call with local variable 
> print Func($value);
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> Error: Cannot assign to an immutable value
> ```

Can anyone tell me what Perl version it's talking about? It talks about named parameters which can be set to be mutable or immutable, something I'm looking for, but the examples given don't work at all for me. I'm using Perl 5.26.3.

Comment: I suspect that the geeksforgeeks page is actually about [tag:raku], not [tag:perl]. If you use [tag:raku] you can use `sub Func(Int $variable)` and `is copy` etc. Otherwise, the closest you get is probably with the `signatures` feature as ikegami suggests.

Comment: That webpage is about Raku (which used to be called Perl 6). Totally different language that is not compatible with Perl 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Anyone can tell what Perl version it's talking about?*

Despite all indications, that snippet isn't Perl at all. It's Raku, the Perl spinoff formerly known as "Perl 6".

Perl has a similar feature called [subroutine signatures](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Signatures). But the parameters are not immutable.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.36;  # For sub signatures

sub f( $param ) {
  $param /= 2;
}

say f( 20 );
```

Output:

```
10
```

---

> *I'm trying to figure out a simple way to make a variable passed as a parameter to a subroutine immutable in the called subroutine*

You can make variables immutable using [Readonly](https://metacpan.org/pod/Readonly).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.10;  # For `say`.

use Readonly qw( Readonly );

sub f {
   Readonly my $param => shift;
   $param /= 2;
}

say f( 20 );
```

Output:

```
Modification of a read-only value attempted at a.pl line 9.
```

Comment: Thanks. I was really confused, especially due to the shebang line that specified perl explicitly.

Comment: That and the fact that the article only mentions "Perl" is to what I was referring when I said "Despite all indications". In the very first sentence, It even links to document that explains that "*The latest version of Perl is 5.28. Perl 6 is different from Perl 5 because it is a fully object-oriented reimplementation of Perl 5.*" So the confusion is quite understandable. (As an aside, that's a weird/misleading/inaccurate way of describing Raku. And 5.28 is 5 years old now, with 5.38 being the latest. This may not be the best site from which to get your information!)